# Get innerHtml of an created element by Javascript

Tags: javascript

I created an element by

```
a = document.createElement("DIV");
a.setAttribute("class", "select-selected");
a.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[selElmnt.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
x[i].appendChild(a);
```

and when i try to get innerHtml of the Class `select-selected` it returns "undefined"

The goal is to switch between Select Option depending the first Choice.

[Here's the code on CodeOpen](https://codepen.io/KarimKha/pen/EqEqao)

Thanks to the community of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is from your method `firstChoice`

```
function firstChoice() {
  var y = document.getElementById("categoryChosen");
  var z = document.getElementsByClassName("select-selected");
  y.style.background = "green";
  y.innerHTML = z.innerHTML;
}
```

`getElementsByClassName` returns a list (hence the plural at "Elements"). And since Arrays (or [NodeLists](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), to be more precise) have no `innerHTML` property, `z.innerHTML` is `undefined`.

Answer (score -1):

I suppose the problem lies in `var z = document.getElementsByClassName("select-selected")`, in your codepen:

```javascript
function firstChoice() {
  var y =       document.getElementById("categoryChosen");
  var z =document.getElementsByClassName("select-selected");
  y.style.background = "green";
  y.innerHTML = z.innerHTML; // <- here's the problem
}
```

`getElementsByClassName` does not return an `Element`, it returns a `NodeList`, from where you have to get the first item to do what you try to do:

```
var z =document.getElementsByClassName("select-selected")[0]; // <- the [0]
```